# How to properly change current track for an Android MediaPlayer instance?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using an Android `MediaPlayer` instance which is simple initialized by:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.conrnfield);
```

I also got this **`Thread`** updating a `SeekBar` according to the track playing progress.

```
    updateTime = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            seekBar.setMax(total);

            while (mediaPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {return;}
                catch (Exception e) {return;}

                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }
        }
    };
```

I got a method to change the current track:

```
public void changeSong(View view) {

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.selectTrack(2);

}
```

However, when I invoke this method, it causes the app to crash. I can see first at the log a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

error message at the stacktrace.

I can't even know if my approach is wrong. This is whole [log](http://www.hastebin.com/vasijorido.avrasm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `MediaPlayer.setDataSource` after a call to `MediaPlayer.reset`. Note that the `MediaPlayer.create` methods are just helper methods that call `MediaPlayer.setDataSource`, and are suppose to be used to play one off media. In the example following context is your Activity so you could probably replace them with `MainActivity.this`.

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(context.getPackageName())
    .appendPath(String.valueOf(R.raw.conrnfield))
    .build();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
```

Comment: Having another media files in the raw folder, how can I properly get the file path for any of them?

Comment: Added an example to the answer.

Comment: Can I really use URI.Builder  like that?

Comment: Yes. That's why I did it.

Comment: It seems I cant get Uri from any package, isnt it Java URI?